# How can I provide Python bindings for variadic template callables with pybind11?

Tags: python, c++, c++17, variadic-templates, pybind11

I am trying to create Python bindings using pybind11 for a C++17 library that has a lot of variadic (member) functions or constructors.

```cpp
// variadic member function
struct Bar
{
    template <typename... Args>
    void baz(Args&&...){ /*...*/ }
};

// variadic constructor
struct Foo
{
    template <typename... Args>
    Foo(Args&&...){ /*...*/ }
};

// variadic free function
template <typename... Args>
void foobar(Args&&...){ /*...*/ }
```

pybind11 [supports positional `*args` arguments](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/functions.html#accepting-args-and-kwargs) and it seems natural to me to use this feature. Unfortuantely, I haven't been able to figure out how to use `pybind11::args` to forward the arguments to the variadic functions.

What would the binding code look like?

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m)
{
    py::class_<Bar>(m, "Bar")
    .def("baz", [](py::args){ /* how do I forward to variadic Bar::baz? */ });

    py::class_<Foo>(m, "Foo")
    .def(py::init<py::args>()); // is this right?

    m.def("foobar", [](py::args){ /* how do I forward to variadic foobar? */ });
}
```

Here are some constraints:

- For my use case, it suffices to support heterogeneous arguments of a certain fixed type in all cases, e.g. it is okay for me to only expose a constructor for `Foo` accepting any number of `Bar` instances.
- I cannot - or am very reluctant to - modify the API of the existing library. As a consequence, having to duplicate every variadic callable with a proxy that accepts e.g. an `std::initializer_list` would make me sad. That being said, some glue code in the binding code is acceptable, as long as it is maintainable.
- Though certainly not beautiful, I can live with restricting the number of variadic arguments to a maximum value, say 20, since the templates must be explicitly instantiated at compile time of the binding code, e.g. via

  ```cpp
  template void foobar();
  template void foobar(Foo&&);
  // ...
  ```

  If it turns out that this is necessary, it would be great if the python user could get an appropriate error message that the maximum number of arguments has been exceeded.
- It doesn't have to be pybind11, I am open to using other libraries if they handle this better.

Comment: You can't dynamically call templates. The C++ compiler has to instantiate them with the correct types. You should rewrite your variadic templates to work with vectors of type erased objects (like `std::any` or `py::object`).

Comment: @unddoch I really don't want to rewrite the existing library if I don't absolutely have to. I don't want the C++ API to be awkward just because we provide Pyhon bindings. I can live with a fixed number of variadic arguments  all of a single fixed known (at compile time) type, so I could explicitly instantiate those templates at compile time of the C++ code generating the bindings. But I still don't know how to cast the elements  of `py::args` to the correct template instantiations.

Comment: @joergbrech use py::cast to cast each element of the py::args object to int and pass them as arguments to the appropriate C++ function (This will also require knowing Types at compile time): [Playground](https://godbolt.org/z/xenGeE4Gs)

Comment: @JishanShaikh Ah thanks! That actually looks much simpler than I thought and it's good enough for my use case. I think I can work with that. I would probably want to add convenience functions that automatically instantiate the templates and that forward to the correct template instantiation, based on the size of `py::args`, e.g. using a switch statement...

Answer (score 2):

Use `py::cast` to cast each element of the `py::args` object to int and pass them as arguments to the appropriate C++ function (This will also require knowing Types at compile time): [Playground](https://godbolt.org/z/EY38GbErn)

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

struct Bar {
    void baz(int x, int y) { /* ... */ }
};

struct Foo {
    Foo(int x, int y) { /* ... */ }
};

void foobar(int x, int y) { /* ... */ }

// Explicitly instantiate the templates for up to 2 int arguments
template void Bar::baz<int, int>(int&&, int&&);
template void Foo::Foo<int, int>(int&&, int&&);
template void foobar<int, int>(int&&, int&&);

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    py::class_<Bar>(m, "Bar")
        .def("baz", [](Bar& self, py::args args) {
            if (args.size() != 2) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Expected 2 arguments");
            }
            int x = py::cast<int>(args[0]);
            int y = py::cast<int>(args[1]);
            self.baz(std::move(x), std::move(y));
        });

    py::class_<Foo>(m, "Foo")
        .def(py::init<int, int>());

    m.def("foobar", [](py::args args) {
        if (args.size() != 2) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Expected 2 arguments");
        }
        int x = py::cast<int>(args[0]);
        int y = py::cast<int>(args[1]);
        foobar(std::move(x), std::move(y));
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction! Here is a version with more "automation": https://godbolt.org/z/Gxh6M3cMj. No need to explicitly instantiate any templates: All needed templates are implicitly instantiated via the instantiations of `invoke_variadic_rt`. My code is still quite verbose and hard to read, I wonder if this can be improved a bit.